# Code changes breaks apk add cache

Tags: docker

Is it possible to split the `apk add` and `go build` commands so that a code change doesn't re-install the apk dependencies?

```
FROM golang:1.8-alpine AS go-build-env
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add --no-cache bash git
RUN go build /bin/webui main.go
```

EDIT: updated

```
FROM golang:1.8-alpine AS go-build-env
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add --no-cache bash git openssh curl g++ \
    make perl; go-wrapper download
RUN mkdir -p /go/src/github.com/markwallsgrove/saml_federation_proxy \
    /go/src/github.com/markwallsgrove/saml_federation_proxy/models \
    /go/src/github.com/markwallsgrove/saml_federation_proxy/webui
COPY webui/main.go /go/src/github.com/markwallsgrove/saml_federation_proxy/webui
COPY models /go/src/github.com/markwallsgrove/saml_federation_proxy/models
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/markwallsgrove/saml_federation_proxy/webui
```

Comment: `apk` is not `apt-get`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dockerfile as written does not contain any `ADD` instructions so `main.go` isn't present.

You're also not dealing with an "`apt-get`" cache as you're using alpine and `apk`, but looking beyond those errors...

In order to keep docker layers cached ignoring code changes, keep them above any `ADD` / `COPY` instructions -- these invalidate all layers below them.

In your example dockerfile it would look something like this:

```
FROM golang:1.8-alpine AS go-build-env
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add --no-cache bash git
ADD main.go .
RUN go build /bin/webui main.go
```

Comment: Thank you Anthony. I have updated the question with the complete & updated chunk from the Dockerfile. I still get the same issue. The first run command always executes and never caches even on consecutive runs.

Comment: @smokedice your dockerfile already satisfies the behaviour in the question